# Python: How to allocate a 'misc' total between other categories

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm building a report in Python to automate a lot of manual transformation we do in Excel at the moment. I'm able to extract the data and pivot it, to get something like this

| Date | Category 1 | Category 2 | Category 3 | Misc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/21 | 40 | 30 | 30 | 10 |
| 02/01/21 | 30 | 20 | 50 | 20 |

Is it possible to divide the misc total for each date in to the other categories by ratio? So I would end up with the below

| Date | Category 1 | Category 2 | Category 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/21 | 44 | 33 | 33 |
| 02/01/21 | 36 | 24 | 60 |

The only way I can think of is to split the misc values off to their own table, work out the ratios of the other categories, and then add misc * ratio to each category value, but I just wondered if there was a function I could use to condense the working on this?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think your solution hits the nail on the head. However it can be quite dense already:

```
>>> cat = df.filter(regex='Category')
>>> df.update(cat + cat.mul(df['Misc'] / cat.sum(axis=1), axis=0))
>>> df.drop(columns=['Misc'])
       Date  Category 1  Category 2  Category 3
0  01/01/21        44.0        33.0        33.0
1  02/01/21        36.0        24.0        60.0
```

`cat.mul(df['Misc'] / cat.sum(axis=1), axis=0)` gets you the reallocated misc values per row, since you multiply each value by `misc` and divide it by the row total. `.mul()` allows to do the the multiplication while specifying along which axis, the rest is about having the right columns.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me pin down exactly what I needed to do (and reassured I was on the right path)